# Flickr API using javascript

Tags: javascript, web-services, flickr

i want to upload photos using flickr,i have no idea about how to start.to be frank iam new to this API.please guide me to start flickr api in java script.

Comment: Do you mean Java? or you really mean JavaScript? AFAICS, its not available, there is `flickrj` and `jickr` though, which are Java APIs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flickr has some JSONP APIs which might be your best bet for using only client-side Javascript.  There's a couple tutorials with using JQuery and Flickr JSONP:
http://www.richardshepherd.com/how-to-use-jquery-with-a-json-flickr-feed-to-display-photos/

http://www.flickr.com/services/api/response.json.html

Good luck!

Comment: i have started developing the api,but i have problems in signature calculation.i cant understand api_sig.

Comment: The first link (richardshepherd.com/...) is no more available.

Answer (score 0):

Flickr has detailed documentation, and I'd suggest that you start by looking [here](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/). They have all the methods listed, and they're easy to read, even for a beginner. Good luck!