# Jquery/Javascript Flickr Gallery.. Need help badly

Tags: javascript, jquery, flickr, image-gallery

So i'm working on a project that basically takes the user's input as a "tag" of sorts for flicker and stores it, to then reuse it to make a gallery of the flicker images it pulls up from the tag. Now I think i've got mostly what i'm trying to do... but It's just not working 100%... or really at all because none of the images show up anymore, but here's my code

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Image Gallery</title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function() {

            $("#test").keyup(function(){
                var value = $(this).val()

                $.getJSON(
                    "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?",
                    {
                        tags: "value",
                        tagmode: "any",
                        format: "json"
                    },
                    function(data) {
                        $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
                            $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");
                            if ( i == 20 ) return false;
                        });
                    }
                );
            };
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form>
        Input a Tag for Flicker Images: <input id="test" type="text" />
    </form>

    <div id="images"></div>

</body>
```

It seems like it's something very simple but I JUST cannot figure out what i'm doing wrong..

Comment: also that if statement should look like this: if(i == 20){return false} if you're gonna have it on one line like that. remember: never forget the curly braces, its just bad practice.

Comment: and could cause unexpected errors

Comment: Oh thats good to know, I'm still learning jquery and I know a good amount of javascript but I'm not "amazing" so every little tip like that helps!

Answer (score 1):

you are missing a semi colon:

```
var value = $(this).val()
```

should be:

```
var value = $(this).val();
```

I would also put a `type="text/javascript"` attribute on your `<script>` tags

one other thing, the closing tags (last two) are:

```
};
});
```

should be

`});` ONLY

here is the rework:

```
$(function() {
    $("#test").keyup(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?", {
            tags: "value",
            tagmode: "any",
            format: "json"
        }, function(data) {
            $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
                $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");
                if (i == 20) return false;
            });
        });
    });
});
```

HERE is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/NFRsX/

Comment: I don't know WHY someone would down vote when I fixed the syntax and then NOT leave a comment.

Comment: Combine it with tags: value (without quotes) and not do the request every keyup, and everything will work like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the double quotes around value;
make `tags:"value" as tags:value`

Also check for parenthesis errors.and your code will run just fine..i made it to work..

Comment: this example: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ has it WITH the double quotes.

Comment: well.. there "cat" is not a variable but here 'value' is a variable so by giving double quotes around you're gonna make that a string..!

Comment: also your could use jquery .abort to cancel xhr requests..incase timeout gives some anomalies.

Answer (score 1):

I tidied up a little your code and can get the following to work:

```
$(function() {

  var url = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?",
      timer;

  var handle = function(data) {
                $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
                    $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");
                    if ( i == 20 ) return false;
                });
              };

  var params = { tagmode: "any",
                 format: "json" };


  $("#test").keyup(function(){
    params['tags'] = $(this).val();
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = window.setTimeout(function(){        
      $.getJSON(url, params, handle);
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

I passed $.getJson as a callback to setTimeout, so you're not hitting flickr on every keystroke.

Comment: You all are LIFE savers!! All of this helps me a TON and it actually works.. i've tried like everything and it just didnt work no matter what I did.. I mean now I need a way to remove the pictures when the tag is remove... but right now i'm not going to worry too much about it.. I kinda like how this works

Answer (score 0):

Using the flickr api on client side requires jsonp. please have a look at question https://stackoverflow.com/a/5945676/24047